# How to follow Semantic Versioning and Keep a Changelog conventions together?

Tags: repository, conventions, release-management, semantic-versioning, changelog

[Keep a Changelog](https://keepachangelog.com/en/1.1.0/) is a wide-used convention that brings some guidelines about the maintenance of a `CHANGELOG.md` file in repositories managed over a VCS.

I'm in doubt about how should it work when it comes of multiple commits of a unique release.
Since its text describes that *"The same types of changes should be grouped"* and its own repo `CHANGELOG.md` file brings the following:

```markdown
...
## [1.0.0] - 2017-06-20
### Added
- New visual identity by [@tylerfortune8](https://github.com/tylerfortune8).
- Version navigation.
- Links to latest released version in previous versions.
- "Why keep a changelog?" section.
- "Who needs a changelog?" section.
...
```

However the same guideline follow [Semmantic Versioning 2.0](https://semver.org/), that defines:

```
...
6. Patch version Z (x.y.Z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if only backwards compatible bug fixes are introduced. A bug fix is defined as an internal change that fixes incorrect behavior.

7. Minor version Y (x.Y.z | x > 0) MUST be incremented if new, backwards compatible functionality is introduced to the public API. It MUST be incremented if any public API functionality is marked as deprecated. It MAY be incremented if substantial new functionality or improvements are introduced within the private code. It MAY include patch level changes. Patch version MUST be reset to 0 when minor version is incremented.
...
```

So I understand that each commit that introduces a bug-fix or a new feature should increase the PATCH or MINOR version respectively.

Is this right?

Comment: I am not clear exactly what conflict you are referring to. It is a best practice to release bug fixes separate from your new features, but not a requirement. If you have both, then the spec is quite clear that if you make a minor version bump and reset the patch. You can only use a patch version if you've added no new features/API's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So I understand that each commit that introduces a bug-fix or a new feature should increase the PATCH or MINOR version respectively.

That is NOT true. There can be many commits leading up to a version bump. You bump the version when you publish your changes, not when you commit them. Note that for some workflows, "official" builds (run on the CI/CD systems) implies publication.

Comment: Hey @jwdonahue. It seems you got the idea here. Your first paragraph address my main confusion, but now I can see. Thanks for share your answer